# Trying to figure out proportion formula for couple of days...

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If you could help please:

I got 4 variables
a = 100; b = 225; c = 375; D = 125
E = a + b + c + d= 825.

I change D sum to 600.

b stays as it is but A, C and D get changed proportionally.

The new variables: A=?; B = 225; C=?;D = ? E = A + B + C = 600.

The new variables A and C and D are in the same proportion of the older variables. How can I figure out the values for A,C,D?

Thank you

Comment: Side note: this question is a mess. Maybe you care to fix it up a little bit, people might take it a little more seriously...

Comment: I've cleaned up my comment Barak. is that better?

Comment: Much better, but please be consistent with your letter-case (e.g., `a` and `A` are not the same). In addition, where did the variable `E` come from (out of nowhere)?

Answer (score 1):

You need $A/C = 100/375$ and $A/D = 100/125$. So $C = 3.75A$ and $D=1.25A$.
Then $A+B+C+D = A + 225 +3.75A +1.25 A = 6A +225 = 600$.  So $A = (600-225)/6$
and $C$ and $D$ follow easily.